# storing content from a Quill form in the database

Tags: javascript, quill

I've been trying a couple of **rich text editors**, and Quill seems to be the best tool to implement into my projects. I'm using Node/Express and MongoDB/Mongoose. In my 'newPost route', I have a form that just takes a title and the main content. Since I'm just testing it out, the title field is outside of the Quill editor. Here the error I'm getting:

[image: Quill_test]

This is after I hit "submit". The console shows not only the title but also the main content that has a code-block with syntax highlight which is exactly what I wanted. But it's not being added to the database.

There's also this message  `Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.`, and it seems I'm required to change Quill's source code myself to fix this.

Getting the main content of the post on the console kind of gave me a feeling that I'm halfway of getting this to work.

Is there a not-so-hard way to get this to work? Thanks!!

---

---

**js**

```
var quill;
var metaData = [];
hljs.configure({   // optionally configure hljs
  languages: ['javascript', 'ruby', 'python']
});
hljs.initHighlighting();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var toolbarOptions = [['blockquote', 'code-block'],
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"], // toggled buttons
    //['blockquote'],
    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
    [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }], // superscript/subscript
    [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }], // outdent/indent
    [{ direction: "rtl" }], // text direction

    [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }], // custom dropdown
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }], // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ font: [] }],
    [{ align: [] }],

    ["clean"] // remove formatting button
  ];
 quill = new Quill("#snow-container", {
    placeholder: "Compose an epic...",
    modules: {
      syntax: true,
      toolbar: toolbarOptions
    },
    theme: "snow"
  });
var oldDelta = {"ops":[{"attributes":{"color":"#000000"},"insert":"This is sample text."}]};
quill.setContents(oldDelta);
});

var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
  // Populate hidden form on submit
  var formContent = document.querySelector('input[name=content]');
  formContent.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());

  console.log("Submitted", $(form).serialize(), $(form).serializeArray());

  // No back end to actually submit to!
  //alert('Open the console to see the submit data!')
  return false;
};
```